# What's the Difference in meaning between 'to-Infinitive' and subordinate conjunction 'that'?

Tags: conjunctions, infinitives, to-infinitive

I'm wondering about 'to-Infinitive' and subordinate conjunction 'that'.

Is there any difference in meaning between following sentences?

- I believe him to be honest.
- I believe that he is honest.

Comment: I think you should ask your second question separately. It's not going to have the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case there is no substantive difference. The version with the infinitive is stiffer and more formal.

Note, however, that with *believe* this equivalence only holds when the complement expresses a current state, with either a stative lexical verb (for example, *be* in your example) or a perfect or progressive construction.

> <sup>ok</sup>I believe (that) he is coming tomorrow.
>   <sup>ok</sup>I believe him to be coming tomorrow.
>
> <sup>ok</sup>I believe that he has come.
>   <sup>ok</sup>I believe him to have come.

You cannot use the infinitive version with a verb expressing a past or future event:

> <sup>ok</sup>I believe that he came yesterday, *but not*
>   <sup>∗</sup> I believe him to come yesterday.
>
> <sup>ok</sup>I believe that he will come tomorrow, *but not*
>   <sup>∗</sup> I believe him to come tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

OK so lets call the first sentence (1) and the other one (2).

So, the **contrast** between sentence (1) and (2) is that in (1) there is ***to infinitive***. However, both (1) and (2) present epistemic commitment to what it is said.

Also, "I believe that he is honest" could be represented with "I know that he is honest".

Last but not least, my dictionary says:

```
I believed (that) he was honest. = I believed him (to be) honest.
```

I hope that I have helped you in some way. :)