# Form of a verb in a direct object of an introductory verb: <Verb> + <Direct Object containing a verb>

Tags: verbs, direct-objects

What is the form of a verb in an infinitive subordinate which is direct object of a verb:

- to-infinitive,
- bare infinitive,
- conjugated verb,
- or gerund?

For example would we say:

- I see the company **to** collapse?
- I see the company collapse?
- I see the company collapse**s**?
- I see the company collaps**ing**?

Thank you in advance for your help.

P.S.: Possible relation with: ['to-Infinitive' and subordinate conjunction 'that'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89702/whats-the-difference-in-meaning-between-to-infinitive-and-subordinate-conjunc), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your first example is ungrammatical. The second and fourth are catenative constructions with "see" as catenative verb and either a bare infinitival clause or a gerund-participial clause as catenative complement. In the third, "(that) the company collapses" is a declarative content clause as complement of "see".